# How to get details of ec2 instances and loadbalancer using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm looking to retrieve information about my AWS EC2 instances and load balancers using the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI). What are the specific AWS CLI commands I can use to get this information? I want to collect details such as instance IDs, IP addresses, load balancer names, and configuration settings for both instances and load balancers.

I've tried **aws ec2 describe-instances** for **instances** and **aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers** for **load balancers**, but I'm not sure how to parse the output effectively. Can someone provide guidance on using these commands and how to filter the results to extract the information I need?

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you should follow guidelines- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Feel free to Edit your question to provide more information. For example, what have you tried? What do you mean by "get details"? What problems are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

As a new user, you likely want to provide some samples of what you have tried.  For example, you have tagged `boto3`, but not provided any code, nor any error message.  So, your code might work, but you might have an authentication problem or vice versa.  We can't help you if we cannot see the error and the code producing it.

We also don't know what you mean by details.  Do you mean the information provided by [CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch.html)?  Do you mean networking information?

In short, the more specifics you can provide the more useful Stack Overflow is!

**Some useful resources:**

[aws-shell](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-shell) - An interactive shell which can help you learn the AWS CLI.  Learning the AWS CLI will help you understand the APIs which are used by `boto3`.

[Boto3 Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html) - Documentation for `Boto3`.